# How to force GCC change the generated assembly order of a branch?

Tags: assembly, gcc, optimization, compiler-construction, clang

My problem is deterministically arranging the position of different branches' code in the compiled binary/assembly. Note that my primary goal is NOT to optimize performance, but to be sure to have a certain branch code right after the branch instruction in assembly.

I tried __builtin_expect_with_probability but it didn't work as expected: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cGd5x49jd

Test code:

```c
int test(int a, int b){
    if (__builtin_expect_with_probability(a!=0, 0, 0.999))
  {
    // code for the unlikely case
    return b+2;
  }
  else
  {
    // code for the likely case
    return b+1;
  }
}
```

Assembly generated by x86_64 gcc 13.2 with `-O0`:

```
test(int, int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-8], esi
        cmp     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 0
        setne   al
        movzx   eax, al
        test    rax, rax
        je      .L2
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        add     eax, 2
        jmp     .L3
.L2:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        add     eax, 1
.L3:
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

And it is not working for clang, either: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/513fh7xeb

UPDATE: thanks to the comments I noted it works for `-O2`, but how to force this happen no matter what optimization option used, except inline asm?

Comment: Please put all code relevant to your question into the question itself.  Stack Overflow questions must be self-standing and understandable even when linked content goes down.  That said, if you need a specific order of branches, you should program in assembly.

Comment: It's working for me.  Using `__builtin_expect_with_probability(a!=0, 1, 0.999)` the order is switched.  Note that without the builtin function, the compiler generates branchless code, which is probably better in this example.  There's also the pragmas `[[likely]]` and `[[unlikely]]` which work to reorder then/else's as well.

Comment: `-O0` tells GCC not to optimize.  So it didn't.  With `-O1` or higher, `0.999` vs. `0.001` reverses the branch layout.

Comment: For `-O0`, does GCC consistently put the `if` body first and the `else` body second?  I'm not optimistic that any optimization hints could do anything when optimization is disabled.  Its code-layout choices aren't even trying to be optimal when it's not optimizing.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for pointing out that. So is this function meant to be working only when optimizations are enabled? Didn't find a related description in the gcc documentation.

Comment: It always works to tell GCC what you think the branch probabilities are.  If GCC isn't optimizing, it doesn't care what they are.  The builtin itself doesn't directly select code layout, it just gives the optimizer more information to work with, overriding its heuristics which guess branch likelihoods.  Even with optimization enabled, there are probably some corner cases for certain surrounding code and if / else bodies where the "likely" path has a taken branch, e.g. if we need to jump somewhere else anyway.  As fuz said, if branch layout is important for correctness, you probably need asm.

Comment: See also https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#index-fno-guess-branch-probability `-fno-guess-branch-probability` and `-freorder-blocks=*algorithm*`  (But note that `-freorder-blocks` won't do anything at `-O0`, as that page says near the top, "Most optimizations are completely disabled at -O0").  `-Og` enables optimization without many optimization passes, so could be a possibility for playing with `-fno-reorder-blocks` or `__builtin_expect` while still having optimization enabled.

Comment: So after your update, the question is "how do I make the compiler optimize in a particular way when I explicitly tell it not to optimize?".  That's a close vote from me...

Comment: @TomV "change the code layout" is not equal to "code optimize" I guess? And my update means "I don't care about optimization for performance", rather than "I explicitly tell it not to optimize".

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for the information. I'll adopt the asm approach.